# addSubview change the index of one object in scroll.subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll, subview

I add objects in `UIScrollView` inside cycle FOR, but after the second interaction the index of `subviews` change.

When i create the `ScrollView`:

```
scroll.subviews :(
"<UIImageView: 0x147aeee0; frame = (1017 186; 7 5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x147aef50>>",
"<UIImageView: 0x147aefa0; frame = (1019 184; 5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x147af010>>"
```

)

After i have the cycle FOR with `[scroll addSubview:btn];`

First

```
scroll.subviews :(
"<UIImageView: 0x147aeee0; frame = (1017 186; 7 5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x147aef50>>",
"<UIImageView: 0x147aefa0; frame = (1019 184; 5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x147af010>>",
"<ContentButton: 0x13fdc610; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (15 10; 221 173); opaque = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x1034cc00>>"
```

)

Second (*change last object to index 0*)

```
scroll.subviews :(
"<ContentButton: 0x13fdc610; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (15 10; 221 173); opaque = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x1034cc00>>",
"<UIImageView: 0x147aefa0; frame = (1019 184; 5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x147af010>>",
"<UIImageView: 0x147aeee0; frame = (1017 186; 7 5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x147aef50>>",
"<ContentButton: 0x105ddf70; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (246 10; 221 173); opaque = NO; tag = 149; layer = <CALayer: 0x105523e0>>"
```

)

Third and so on, the object will add normally (in last index)

```
scroll.subviews :(
"<ContentButton: 0x13fdc610; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (15 10; 221 173); opaque = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x1034cc00>>",
"<UIImageView: 0x147aefa0; frame = (1019 184; 5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x147af010>>",
"<UIImageView: 0x147aeee0; frame = (1017 186; 7 5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x147aef50>>",
"<ContentButton: 0x105ddf70; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (246 10; 221 173); opaque = NO; tag = 149; layer = <CALayer: 0x105523e0>>",
"<ContentButton: 0x13f1dc80; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (477 10; 221 173); opaque = NO; tag = 3; layer = <CALayer: 0x13f1dd20>>"
```

)

The problem is in the second interaction, so why the last object (`ContentButton`) was in the index 2 and change into index 0?

```
for (obj * objScroll in arrayChaObj)
    {                
        // UIButton
        ContentButton * btn = [[ContentButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(btContentPosXChaObj,
                                                                    10,
                                                                    imgButtonScroll.size.width,
                                                                    imgButtonScroll.size.height)];

        btContentPosXChaObj += 10 + imgButtonScroll.size.width;
        [scroll addSubview:btn];

        NSLog(@"scroll.subviews :%@",scroll.subviews);
        [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(btContentPosXChaObj, imgButtonScroll.size.height+10)];
    }
```

Comment: Does it happen when you add the button or when you change content size?

Comment: i just figure out thanks to your question, is because the content size, if i comment the "setContentSize" is ok and index didn't change... but i can't understand why

Answer (score 1):

This is just a wild guess.

What happens when you call `setContentSize:` for the first time? Well, the two image views end up outside the content region. They won't be ever displayed.

I guess the scrollview then optimizes the order of subviews and puts the invisible ones to the end which can probably improve its clipping (redrawing) functionality.

Currently I don't have the time to check this and experiment but it's a reasonable explanation for me.

Comment: If this is true, it's a shame it's undocumented.

Comment: Probably is true, i put "setContentSize" before "addSubview" and is good. (i will wait for someone confirm that is a exactly the answer) thanks

Comment: @silvaric Why do you have views outside the content bounds at the first place?

Comment: i don't know, the first NSLog is after create the scroll (alloc), i add only "ContentButton"